# Update to Froyo -=> reboot loop on Sanyo Zio

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, reboot, system-freeze

I have a Sanyo Zio.  It was happily rooted and working until last night when the OTA update to FroYo arrived.

Now, it boots, gets to the desktop, and freezes.

It looks like it's still running, as I can follow the log with adb (something I just learned about).  The log continues to accumulate entries if, for example, I touch the screen.

Otherwise, it is just completely paralyzed and unresponsive.  It has the wrong date and time (currently 11:12PM on November 10) and doesn't connect to its network.  It does, however, show the charging icon if I plug it in.  It is alive in there somewhere.

What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

1. Do a factory reset ([here are instructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=967973)).
2. Grab the update from [here](https://www.yousendit.com/dl?phi_action=app/orchestrateDownload&rurl=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.yousendit.com%252Ftransfer.php%253Faction%253Dbatch_download%2526send_id%253D1049341551%2526email%253Dded8b7cc13d4afcbfd41e1b4ea22da3a) (dead link) and re-flash it.  You may need to put it in the `/sdcard` folder and name it update.zip, or use Fastboot through adb (you need to install the Android SDK on your PC).

Comment: When I try to do a factory reset, it goes to fastboot.

Comment: You'll see in the second post in that thread that you can factory reset from within fastboot.

Comment: OK, now I need that update.zip fie, but the location seems to have expired.  Are they all the same or do I need the one specifically for the Zio?

Comment: Shoot.  Yes, you do need one specifically for the Zio.  I can't find one at the moment but a good place to look is in the General or Android Dev sub-forums for the Zio on XDA: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1060

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with restoring your phone to factory settings, then I would try that.  Note that you WILL lose all internal data on the phone.  Your apps, contacts, mail, calendar, etc. will sync back from the cloud.  Everything on your SD card will be fine.  But any application data and settings stored on the internal memory will be lost.

[See here for more information on how to reset your Sanyo Zio](http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1670312-Sanyo-Kyocera-ZIO-M6000-Cricket-Reset)